# Store the sum result of a list into another one?

Tags: python, list, sum

I'm trying to sum the elements of a list and then store the result of each sum in another list.

So far I have this:

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]    
print(sum(int(i) for i in array1))
```

The output is 10.

But what I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
input = [1, 2, 3, 4]    
output = [1, 3, 6, 10]
```

Do I need to store the value into the second list in each step?

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Python 3.2 or higher, there is already a function for this, [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
import itertools

input = [1,2,3,4]  

output = list(itertools.accumulate(input))
```

If you're on a pre-3.2 version of Python, you can always borrow the equivalent code given in the `accumulate` documentation:

```
def accumulate(iterable, func=operator.add):
    'Return running totals'
    # accumulate([1,2,3,4,5]) --> 1 3 6 10 15
    # accumulate([1,2,3,4,5], operator.mul) --> 1 2 6 24 120
    it = iter(iterable)
    try:
        total = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    yield total
    for element in it:
        total = func(total, element)
        yield total
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension is probably not the easiest way.  You could do this:

```
input = [1, 2, 3, 4]
output = []
total = 0
for i in input:
    total += i
    output.append(total)
```

Comment: Thanks, so the deal here is to append each result into a new array(total), It is very clear now.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want, but is maybe not that good to understand...

```
output = [sum(array1[:i+1]) for i in range(len(array1))]
```

You can also do it like this (which should be easier to understand):

```
i = 0
output = []
for item in array1:
    i += item
    output.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might numpy useful if you are doing a lot if numeric operations, the [cumsum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) method would do what you want here:

```
In [11]: import numpy as np

In [12]: array1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [13]: array1.cumsum()
Out[13]: array([ 1,  3,  6, 10])
```

It is easy to apply the same logic using python:

```
def cumsum(l):
    it = iter(l)
    sm = next(it, 0)
    yield sm
    for i in it:
        sm += i
        yield sm
```

Demo:

```
In [16]: array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [17]: list(cumsum(array1))
Out[17]: [1, 3, 6, 10]
```